Eclipse 2024-09 Java Project Facet only includes Java version numbers up to 17 despite JDK 23 being installed
Below you can see that I have JDK 23 set as the runtime.  Why is there no Java version beyond version 17 available to me?


Did you add JDK23 support?

This confirms that the Sept Eclipse release only supports JDK22 which is apparently not installed on your system. Likewise it also states it can support JDK23, but a patch is required, which is what the other link showed.

Java 23 support is in Eclipse 2024-12 which is now available.
